# Multiple classes with onmouseenter/leave event?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have multiple items with the same class I want to change when the user hovers over them.
I could add the events like this in the HTML but this seems rather unpretty:

```
<div class="video-item" onmouseenter="overVideoStart(this)"></div>
```

The JavaScript looks like this:

```
function overVideoStart(element)
{
    element.className += " video-item-hover";
    ...
}
```

Is there a more good looking way to do this? I wish to leave the onmouseenter attribute away and instead have it defined in the JavaScript file. There is a way to do this for single items but I haven't found a way to do this for classes. I'm sorry if this is a total noob question but this is my first time I'm working with JavaScript.

Comment: why not css `:hover` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to add events to elements in JS.

To add event listeners to multiple elements you would need to capture all the elements first and loop through them and set each one to have a listener.

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.video-item');
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
   elements[i].addEventListener("mouseenter",mouseEnter);
}

function mouseEnter(e){
    //e will refer to the event object
    //you can refer to the element with keyword "this"
}
```

If you include a library like jQuery you can shorten the code a little as it will do the looping and other work behind the scenes

```
jQuery('.video-item').mouseenter(mouseEnter);

function mouseEnter(e){
    //e will refer to the event object
    //you can refer to the element with keyword "this"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) to your webpage, and use it's css selector like queries to set at once callbacks for elements that match the query.

For example in your case:

```
jQuery(".video-item").mouseenter(function(event) {
    // handle the mouse enter
});
```

Or, if the matching elements can change over time - e.g. via ajax calls - you can use the more powerful [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function.